# how can I set DeploymentOptions for main verticle

Tags: vert.x

How can I set

```
DeploymentOptions options = new DeploymentOptions().setWorker(true);
```

for a main verticle?

I need something like

```
@Override
    public void init(Vertx vertx, Context context) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.init(vertx, context);
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. If you deploy verticles manually, then you can just work with `DeploymentOptions`:

   ```
   DeploymentOptions options = new DeploymentOptions();
   // <options configuration>
   vertx.deployVerticle("com.mycompany.MyVerticle", options);
   ```
2. If you use [vertx command line tool](http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/java/#_the_vertx_command_line), then `vertx run` command can take a few optional parameters. For your question, `-worker` option determines whether the verticle is a worker verticle or not.
3. If you use Vert.x [Launcher](https://github.com/eclipse/vert.x/blob/3.4.1/src/main/java/io/vertx/core/Launcher.java) class, then you can inherit from it and customize some hook methods from [VertxLifecycleHooks](https://github.com/eclipse/vert.x/blob/3.4.1/src/main/java/io/vertx/core/impl/launcher/VertxLifecycleHooks.java) interface.

Comment: Is there a way to use LifecycleHooks when using AbstractVerticle instead of Launcher?

Comment: You have verticle, which extends `AbstractVerticle` and has `static void main`? Or how do you deploy your verticle?

Comment: no static void main. I use "extends AbstractVerticle" and have @Override public void start().

Comment: Unfortunately no, you can't do this. If you have some custom deployer, then you have to patch it's code to add this functionality.